# Trying to understand the final expression when the integral has be evaluated?

Tags: integration

Suppose that  $f ∈ C [1,3]$ and let $g:[1,3] \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$g(x)= \frac{1+\ln(x^3)}{x}$$

Given that $g$ is an increasing function, show that

$$\int^3_1f(x)g(x) = [\ln3+\frac{3}{2}(\ln3)^2]f(\zeta)$$

for some$$\zeta \in [1,3]$$

My attempted solution below :-

$$g(x) = \frac{1+\ln(x^3)}{x}$$

Rewrite as the following

$$\int^3_1\frac{3\ln x+1}{x}\,dx$$

$$u = 3\ln x+1$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{3}{x}$$

$$dx = du \frac{x}{3}$$

Applying the anti derivative

$$\int^3_1\frac{u}{x}\frac{x}{3}\,du$$

$$\int^3_1\frac{u}{3}\,du$$

$$\implies\Bigl[\frac{u^2}{6}\Bigr]^3_1$$

$$\frac{u^2}{6} = \frac{(3\ln x+1)^2}{6} = \frac{9\ln x^2+6\ln x+1}{6}= {\frac{3}{2}\ln x^2 + \ln x+1/6}$$

$$\implies [\frac{3}{2}\ln x^2+\ln x+1/6]^3_1$$

When I make the substitution, I get the following :-

$$\Bigl\{\tfrac{3}{2}\ln(3)^2+\ln(3)+\tfrac{1}{6}\} - \{\tfrac{3}{2}\ln(1)^1+\ln(1)+\tfrac{1}{6}\Bigr\}$$

$$\implies\Bigl\{ \tfrac{3}{2}\ln(3)^2+\ln(3) \Bigr\}$$

The solution has

$$\int^3_1f(x)g(x) = [\ln(3)+\frac{3}{2}\ln(3)^2]f(\zeta)$$

When evaluating the integral of g(x) i got the ln expression as shown what i am trying to understand is the f($\zeta$) which is multiplied by the expression ?

The information given is f $f\in C[1,3]$ so I am assuming this $f(x)$ can be placed in front of the integral while the integral of $g(x)$ is evaluated, where f($\zeta$) can be any value within the interval $[1,3]$. I'm not sure and I am just seeking some clarification as it relates to this $f(\zeta)$ in the final expression?

Comment: What do you mean, "given that $g$ is an increasing function"? I get $(2-3\ln x)/x^2$ for its derivative, which is negative at, for example, $x=e\in[1,3]$. Did you mean to say $f$ instead of $g$?

Comment: thats how the question was stated i know for an increasing function that can be defined as where x < y where the first value of the function is less than the second and so forth but im not sure in relation to this question the application of the statement i dont know if it has any relation to the f(ζ). @BarryCipra just to confirm yeah the question is stated as g is an increasing function.

Answer (score 1):

Note that g(x) is positive on $[1,3]$

Try to show that  $$\int _1^3 f(x)g(x)dx = f(\zeta)\int _1^3 g(x)dx$$ using the continuity of $f(x)$ on $[1,3]$

All you have to do is to show that $$m\le \frac {\int _1^3 f(x)g(x)dx }{ \int _1^3 g(x)dx}\le M$$

where $m$s and $M$ are the minimum and maximum value of $f(x)$  on the interval $[1,3]$

Comment: Ok so im looking at what your saying, so far i have evaluated the integral and gotten  the above expression for the integral of g(x) but i am assuming that based on what your saying that making the substitution for the integral you will remain with $$m \leq f(\zeta) \leq M $$

Comment: $$m \leq  \frac{f(\zeta)\int^3_1g(x)dx}{\int^3_1g(x)dx} \leq M$$ based on the information i just used the information and substituted where $f(\zeta)$ lies between a min and a max value is this essentially what your saying

Comment: @Amir that is correct. We do not know what is $\zeta$ but we know is between $1$ and$ 3$

Comment: thanks for the clarification i appreciate it @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani